# run function on DataFrame based on mulitindex level and append it to new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a time history dataset from different mass drops on different locations.
I loaded the data and structurized the data by a multi index based on the masses and locations.
Now I want to do a fourier transform and append the amplitudes and frequencies to new colums.

For now I cannot find how to run a FFT method for each mass separaty

I tried to call one column and put it in my fuction.
Whereas the outcome is put in the new columns.

now two problems occur:

1.) The result of the function has not the same length as the time signal, I want to fill the rest with Nan.

2.) if I have a result that has the same length, it seems to be from the full column and not from each `('loc','mass')` separately.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def fft(a,n):
    b =[]
    for i in range(len(a)//2):
        b.append(a[i]+a[-i])
    return b,n

def fft_two(a,n):
    b = sum(a)
    return a*n+b,n    

col = ['loc', 'mass', 'time', 'signal']

loc = ['loc1'] * 10+['loc2'] * 10
mass = (['10kg']*5+['20kg']*5)*2
time = list(range(0,5))*4
ampl = list(np.random.rand(5))*4

a= [loc,mass,time,ampl]
pf = pd.DataFrame(a, index=col).T

pfi=pf.set_index(['loc','mass'])

pfi['ampl'], pfi['freq']= fft_two(pfi['signal'],n=4)
```

now I got:

```
        time    signal      ampl        freq
loc mass                
loc1    10kg    0   0.781256    14.0339     4
    10kg    1   0.553895    13.1244     4
    10kg    2   0.154589    11.5272     4
    10kg    3   0.546888    13.0964     4
    10kg    4   0.690581    13.6712     4
    20kg    0   0.781256    14.0339     4
    20kg    1   0.553895    13.1244     4
    20kg    2   0.154589    11.5272     4
    20kg    3   0.546888    13.0964     4
    20kg    4   0.690581    13.6712     4
loc2    10kg    0   0.781256    14.0339     4
    10kg    1   0.553895    13.1244     4
    10kg    2   0.154589    11.5272     4
    10kg    3   0.546888    13.0964     4
    10kg    4   0.690581    13.6712     4
    20kg    0   0.781256    14.0339     4
    20kg    1   0.553895    13.1244     4
    20kg    2   0.154589    11.5272     4
    20kg    3   0.546888    13.0964     4
    20kg    4   0.690581    13.6712     4
```

I want a result for each specific loc and mass:

```
        time    signal      ampl        freq
loc mass                
loc1    10kg    0   0.781256    ampl1       freq1
        10kg    1   0.553895    ampl1       freq1
        10kg    2   0.154589    ampl1       freq1
        10kg    3   0.546888    nan         nan
        10kg    4   0.690581    nan         nan
        20kg    0   0.781256    ampl2       freq2
        20kg    1   0.553895    ampl2       freq24
        20kg    2   0.154589    ampl2       freq2
        20kg    3   0.546888    nan         nan
        20kg    4   0.690581    nan         nan
loc2    10kg    0   0.781256    ampl3       freq3
        10kg    1   0.553895    ampl3       freq3
        10kg    2   0.154589    ampl3       freq3
        10kg    3   0.546888    nan         nan
        10kg    4   0.690581    nan         nan
        20kg    0   0.781256    ampl4       freq4
        20kg    1   0.553895    ampl4       freq4
        20kg    2   0.154589    ampl4       freq4
        20kg    3   0.546888    nan         nan
        20kg    4   0.690581    Nan         nan
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group the multiindex that is constructed from `pf`.

```
pfi=pf.set_index(['loc','mass'])
for grp in pfi.groupby(["loc", "mass"]):
    print("group {} {}".format(*grp[0]))
    print("{}".format(grp[1]))
```

Once you have grouping working, then you can `apply()` functions to those groups.

```
pfi.groupby(["loc", "mass"])["signal"].apply(fft_two)
```

But you wish to parameterize `fft_two` and for that, you can redefined `fft_two` to accept arguments from the `apply()` invocation.

```
def fft_two(a,args):
    n = args[0]
    b = sum(a)
    return a*n+b,n
```

```
pfi.groupby(["loc", "mass"])["signal"].apply(fft_two,args=(4,))
```

Inside of `fft_two()` you will then get a `Series` and `n` of 4 and can then alter the implementation of your fft function as desired.

The return value of `fft_two()` may be assigned to a new columne of `pfi` or a new `DataFrame` can be created based on the `groupby()` returned keys tuple and series.